# do mobile redirect without js

Tags: html, mobile, redirect

for some mobiles where browsers does not support JS, for such devices how we can do mobile redirects. I  have HTML pages website, cannot place a scriptual language there.

your advice plzz ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use only jquery or or htaccess redirect or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```